# search in txt file then print in new txt file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, search

i have txt file which containt over 1000 line, the data in it like:

```
alpha
hmld ahge 573
otndgd fhj 29
fidnt ank 1962

beta
jdkrs 2
adny 14
urmekhjf 6893
...
```

how i can search and print (in new txt file) for any line containt somthing like (dn), and the result like:

```
fidnt ank 1962 alpha
adny 14 beta
```

i search by gedit but it's deffecult.
my system: ubuntu

best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```bash
<input-file.txt awk '
     !NF {FNR=0; next}
  FNR==1 {header=$0; next}
    /dn/ {print $0, header}' > result.txt
```

Where we reset the per-`F`ile `R`ecord `N`umber every time a blank line is found, then the first line after that (when `FNR` is 1) is deemed the *header*, and we print the record followed by that *header* wherever `dn` is found in the input.

Comment: thank you, how i can search for "dn" and "mt" ..(list in values.txt). regards

Comment: @hafmoon, that'd be a different question. Please ask separately.

Comment: ok, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713686/search-in-txt-file-and-every-result-in-new-file

Answer (score 2):

Basic grep:

```bash
grep 'dn' input-file.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: thank you, but the result of your code without the heads of the data "alpha", "beta", ...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fair, fixed.

Comment: @hafmoon you don't mention any "heads" in your question. You say you want lines with `dn`. What defines the header? Please edit your question and clarify what you need.