# search in txt file and every result in new file

Tags: awk, sed, search

For context, this is a follow-up on [search in txt file then print in new txt file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/713676) with a few extra complications.

I have 2 txt files the first one is data.txt file which contains over 2000 lines, the data in it like:

```
alpha
hmld 573
otndgd 29
fidnt 1962

beta
jdkrshm 2
adny 14
urmekhjf 6893
...
```

the 2nd file is values.txt,

I want to search and print (in new txt file) for any line containing one of list of values in values.txt like

```
dn
hm
sf
```

, and the result1.txt like (with the head like "alpha"):

```
fidnt 1962 alpha
adny 14 beta
```

and the result2.txt like:

```
hmld 573 alpha
jdkrshm 2 beta
```

my system: ubuntu

best regards

Comment: You probably need to give more detailed instructions about how the "headings" can be differentiated. Are they all English spellings of Greek letters? Do they all have blank lines before them? Are they the only lines without numbers? What criteria can be used to pick them out? You should also post what you've tried so far and what trouble you're having. The point of this site is to answer specific questions, not to get other people to work for you for free.

Comment: 1st q: no it's utf-8 , 2nd Q: yes there are empty line before any header, 3rd Q: every header without numbers, 4 Q: no criteria.

Comment: "no it's utf-8" does not answer the first question, and "every header without numbers" does not answer the third: Are they the *only* lines without numbers? Are they the *only* lines with blank lines before them? Does even the first header have a blank line above it? If there are no criteria by which one can differentiate the headers, then what you ask is clearly impossible.

Comment: There are other questions that need answering too: can the headers be repeated? can the content lines be repeated, and if so, do you want the result to read "hmld 573 alpha beta" or have two lines, one with alpha, one with beta?

Comment: What should happen if one of the strings in values.txt match on the header line of each block? For example if values.txt contained `ph` should `alpha ph` be output or is it only the non-empty lines after each header that should be tested?

Answer (score 1):

Again, `awk`'s your friend here:

```
awk '
  !values_processed {
    result[$0] = "result"FNR".txt"; next
  }
  !NF {FNR=0; next}
  FNR==1 {header=$0; next}
  {
    for (value in result)
      if (index($0, value))
        print $0, header > result[value]
  }' values.txt values_processed=1 data.txt
```

That's using the same approach as in [the answer to your earlier question](/a/713679), but getting the list of values from the lines of the `values.txt` file into an associative array which records the name of the output file for each value based on the line number in `values.txt`, and looking for them in `data.txt` using `index()` instead of `/regex/` matching to do a substring search.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is (untested):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        out[$1] = "result" NR ".txt"
        next
    }
    {
        for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            for ( str in out ) {
                if ( index($i,str) ) {
                    print $i, $1 > out[str]
                }
            }
        }
    }
' values.txt RS='' FS='\n' data.txt
```

That could exceed a "too many open files" threshold if values.txt is large. If that's an issue let us know.